# Remove fields from object inside a pipeline stage i.e. not using $unset/$project in a separate stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

It is clear to add/overwrite 1 or more fields to an object in a pipeline, we can use `$mergeObjects`:

```js
{$project: {X: {$mergeObjects: [ '$$CURRENT', {foo:'bar', fin:7} ]}} }
```

Is there a compact way to *remove* fields?  The best I have is:

```js
{$project: {X: {$arrayToObject: {$filter: {
                                  input: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"},
                                  cond: {$not:{$in:['$$this.k', ['foo','fin']]}}
                }}}
}}
```

We'd really like the following but this does not work:

```js
{$project: {X: {$mergeObjects: [ '$$CURRENT', {foo:'$$REMOVE', fin:'$$REMOVE'} ]}} }
```

This is a generic pipeline operator challenge.  It is not specific to a shape of input nor is there a target output.  For the want of a real example, consider these input docs:

```js
    {"brand": "B1", "color": "red", o1:"A1", o2:["B","C"]},
    {"brand": "B1", "color": "red", o1:"A2", o2:["D","E"]},
    {"brand": "B1", "color": "blue", o1:"A2", o2:["D","E"]},
...
```

I wish to group by brand and color and then perform operations on the material (e.g. `cnt` below) *as well as* carry along "the rest of the doc" for other operations including `$project`.  This is straightforward with `$group` and `$$CURRENT` but it copies `brand` and `color` into the `$push` array:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {c:'$color',b:'$brand'}, cnt: {$sum:1}, XX: {$push: "$$CURRENT"}}}
]);

{
    "_id" : {
        "c" : "red",
        "b" : "B1"
    },
    "cnt" : 2,
    "XX" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "brand" : "B1",  // duped because of generic pickup by $$CURRENT
            "color" : "red", // duped because of generic pickup by $$CURRENT
            "o1" : "A1",
            "o2" : [
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "brand" : "B1", // duped because of generic pickup by $$CURRENT
            "color" : "red", // duped because of generic pickup by $$CURRENT
            "o1" : "A2",
            "o2" : [
                "D",
                "E"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The fields going into the `$group` `_id` can be removed from the object going into `$push` with the `objectToArray-filter-arrayToObject` pattern.  The question is:  is there a more compact way to remove 1 or more fields from an object?

Comment: if you can give a sample json and the expected output, to help so we know what you want to do

Comment: I thought I did.  :-)   But I will add additional color.

Comment: i mean the data in json, and the expected result in json, so we see what the query should do

Answer (score 0):

We have 3 stage operators to remove fields

- `$project and field : 0`
- `$set and and  field : $$REMOVE`
- `$unset field`

They take as arguments

- a root field
- or a field path

Limitations

- They don't accept variable fields for example i cant
  `{$project : {"$$aField" : 0 }}` meaning i can't use them with dynamic keys
- the path sometimes is very general, for example i might want to remove the field in the first 2 members of an array and not from all array members

For the last 2 cases we can

- unwind to make the nested document more flat to be able to use stage operators  (still dont fix the dynamic keys problem)
- use the object to array, filter, and back to object which is slow and complicated

*MongoDB doesnt support for now `removeKey($$document,$$key)` also we dont have a way to access nested fields with creteria in an easy way, without nested map functions etc. Until they add those, i think we don't have alternative.

Query

- this is an example of using a path to remove fields from nested documents
- in your group, you could also unset before grouping if you didnt want some fields to added in the `$push $$CURRENT`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71068981-m)

```js
aggregate([{"$unset":["XX.o1", "XX.o2"]}])
```

Comment: Good engagement -- but the question seeks an "interstage" answer -- not using `$project` or `$unset`.

Comment: i told you there is no way to do this, we dont have removeField operator. we only have convert to array and filter, or somehow manage to use project/set. there is no answer, maybe ask to add it on mongodb, there is a site for those

Comment: see [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-missing-basic-document-object-operators/8747), i asked that in mongodb forums long time ago, i hope they fix those sometime, to add those operators and to work with variables also